# Unnest row labels from pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

My goal is to use the results of my pivot table as a raw data set for further manipulation, however I can't figure out how to easily break out my nested row labels and copy down the parent value for every child row, in it's own column.

Example:

```
Row Labels   | Sum of Qnty   
Account1     |    15        
  - 21325231 |    5        
  - 54737437 |    5         
  - 43264326 |    5
Account2     |    20
  - 47473466 |    5
  - 23572755 |    10
  - 43623673 |    5
```

I would like to show that as a normal table:

```
AccountNm |  Contract   | Value
Account1  |   21325231  | 5
Account1  |   54737437  | 5
Account1  |   43264326  | 5
Account2  |   47473466  | 5
Account2  |   23572755  | 10
Account2  |   43623673  | 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the pivot table you should now see two more menu options[image]

Step 1. Click on design -> report layout -> Show in Tabular Form.

Step 2. Click on design -> report layout -> Repeat All Item Labels

That should do it.