# Making a collated transaction report using a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, report

I'm trying to summarize donations to a non-profit and collate names, yearly contributions, and contact info on a nice clean report, one row per user. I got the yearly sums working using a PivotTable, but have hit several dead ends for getting the contact information on the same line. Here's an example of my input data and a start on the PivotTable:

[example input data and pivot table start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Sv2.png)

I'd like the email column to show up right alongside. I believe I can guarantee that the contact info will always be the same for each users' contribution. Am I able to get what I want in excel?

Or should I settle for a separate sheet that just shows the list of users from a different csv from the donation management site (Little Green Light) and the end user needs to cross reference them?

Here's the test xlsx file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lhh5w455x8j8mz/test_report.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Use Power Query (`Data => Get & Transform`), available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365.  If you Pivot on the years, the defaults will do the Sum and also retain the email column.

Comment: How about create a formula as a secondary column?

Comment: You should just be able to add the email as an extra row item to your pivot. If needed reformat your pivot like this: https://superuser.com/questions/1345883/unnest-row-labels-from-pivot-table/1345997#1345997

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm able to get this working properly. Would I write this up as an answer?

Comment: @Lee It's tricky, since I need to collate and iterate through the unique list of names that the Pivot Table created. Might be possible, but don't know how currently without downloading a separate csv.

Comment: @gns100 This sort of works, but I can't see how to rearrange the "email" column to be to the right of the yearly sums contribution (the email is not as important as the contribution amount, unfortunately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data sournce
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}, {"email", type text}}),

//Pivot on years
//then re-order columns to desired order
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US")[Year]), "Year", "Amount", List.Sum),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Name", "2021", "2022", "email"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]