# Excel: Fill empty labels in a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel 16 for macOS. I have a pivot table that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to do the following so that I can make it more like a standard dataframe:

1. Fill in empty values in the columns - so fill all column A with `2014`, all column B with `Q1`, etc.
2. Exclude the totals - so lose the columns with "Aylesbury Total", "Basildon Total", etc.

If I go to Pivot Table Options, my options are quite limited - in particular, options relating to empty rows and columns are greyed out:

[image]

Is there a way I can do the above?

[Update] Here is the "Layout" tab:

[image]

And here is the "Data" tab:

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking it is in the "layout" tab in your screenshot. The windows and web version are both in different places, but are in a layout "area". It should say something like items labels and give you an option to repeat or not repeat.

Comment: Thanks! I've added screenshots of the Layout and Data tabs - but I don't see anything relevant in either of those :( Perhaps this is just something that macOS Excel doesn't offer?

Comment: I fired up my mac version of excel and it looks the same as the windows version. Here is how to do it: https://superuser.com/questions/1345883/unnest-row-labels-from-pivot-table/1345997#1345997